# Como redirigir correctamente a otra página en react tras un formulario

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql

Para empezar, tengo una tabla con una lista de coches:

```
create table coche(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  fabricante varchar,
  anno_fabricacion integer,
  precio integer,
  plazas integer,
  foto varchar unique
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, tengo este formulario para añadir un nuevo coche:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createCoche } from '../lib/coche.js';

const CrearCoche = () => {
  const [nom, setNom] = useState('');
  const [fab, setFab] = useState('');
  const [ann, setAnn] = useState(0);
  const [pre, setPre] = useState(0);
  const [pla, setPla] = useState(0);
  const [fot, setFot] = useState('');

  const ajuNom = (event) => {
    setNom(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuFab = (event) => {
    setFab(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuAnn = (event) => {
    setAnn(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuPre = (event) => {
    setPre(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuPla = (event) => {
    setPla(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuFot = (event) => {
    setFot(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const introducecoche = () => {
    const co = {
      nombre: nom,
      fabricante: fab,
      anno_fabricacion: ann,
      precio: pre,
      plazas: pla,
      foto: fot,
    };
    createCoche(co);
    alert('¡El coche ha sido creado correctamente!');
    window.location.replace('/coche');
  };

  return (
    <main className="crear-profe">
      <h2>Introduzca los datos del nuevo coche</h2>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Nombre:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={ajuNom} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Fabricante:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={ajuFab} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Año de fabricación:</label>
          <input type="number" onChange={ajuAnn} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>precio:</label>
          <input type="number" onChange={ajuPre} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Plazas:</label>
          <input type="number" onChange={ajuPla}></input>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Foto:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={ajuFot} />
        </div>

        <button className="btn" type="button" onClick={introducecoche}>
          Crear Coche
        </button>
        <br />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};

export default CrearCoche;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que cuando pulse en "Crear Coche" se introducirá el coche en la Base de Datos y el usuario será redirigido a la página de la lista de coches, pero cuando regreso veo que el coche no se añadió.
Si quito del código el `window.location.replace('/coche');` si que se introduce el coche, lo que me indica que el problema esta ahí. También he notado que si el formulario tuviera solo 2 o 3 campos en vez de los 6 de este ejemplo si que funciona, lo que significa que al ordenador no le da tiempo a procesar todos los datos del formulario antes de que `window.location.replace` actué, causando este error.
¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que pueda usar el formulario y ser después redirigido sin que pasen este error?

Comment: Tendrías que hacerlo como función de `callback` de `createCoche()` ya que tal como lo tienes no espera a que finalice la llamada para redirigir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es lanzar la redirección cuando acabe la llamada (esperar a que finalice), lo que se conoce como función de `callback`.

Por ejemplo, cuando llamas a `createCoche(co)` le añades una función como parámetro, tal que así:

```
createCoche(co, () => {
    // código para la redirección
})
```

Y en la definición de la función:

```
const createCoche = (coche, callback) => {
    // llamada ajax al servicio

    // cuando finalice la llamada
    callback && callback()
}
```

Recuerda que, si no lo tienes ya implementado, tendrás que controlar los tiempos de la llamada AJAX con `async/await` para esperar a que acabe.